# C++ Constructor error when I separate the function prototype from the definition

Tags: c++

When I have both the prototype and definition in the same header file (as shown below), and I create an object in main (source.cpp) with `Cube c1{};` I get no error and the default constructor works; c1's side will be defaulted to 0.0

```
class Cube {
    private:
        double side;
        static int counter; 
                                                   //this is cube.h       
    public:
        Cube(double s = 0.0) :side{ s } {  //constructor
            counter++;
        }
};
```

However, when I separate the interface from the implementation like this:

```
class Cube {
    private:
        double side;
        static int counter;  //static data
                                                   //this is cube.h
    public:
        Cube(double);
};
```

Its implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cube.h"

int Cube::counter{ 0 };

                                                   //this is cube.cpp
Cube::Cube(double s = 0.0) :side{ s } {
    counter++;
}
```

And I go to the main function in source.cpp, `Cube c1{};` now gives me the error:

```
no instance of constructor "Cube::Cube" matches the argument list
```

Note: When I gave c1 a value, like `Cube c1{5};` it works in both cases.

Comment: You need to put the default parameter in the constructor declaration, not the definition.  I'm surprised the compiler doesn't raise a warning or error to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the default argument to the declaration `Cube(double = 0.0);`, not the definition. Otherwise the matching function cannot be found in other files.